# How to negative the yaw of a quaternion

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I'm writing code that receives quaternion values that are used to rotate a 3D model. To display the model with the correct rotation, though, I'll need to negate the yaw (rotation about the z axis). Since I can't change the code that produces the input quaternion, is it possible to negate the yaw of a quaternion? I would like to do this without converting the quaternion to Euler angles to avoid issues if the pitch is 90 degrees.